# Grunt and Bower config issue

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, gruntjs, bower

I am fighting a weird problem that has caused me to pull my hair out multiple times. For a project we are working on we are using bower and grunt to deal with dependencies etc... everything seems to be fine except our angular app is looking for all the stuff to be put in the bower_dep folder.   It does this on every one elses machine ... on my machine however when bower goes out and gets dependencies it puts them in app/bower_dep and my app doesnt find them ... on top of that of course if i forget to manually copy the stuff over the app winds up breaking in spectacular fashion.

The question here becomes why would grunt/bower be putting my dependencies in app/bower_dep rather than /bower_dep like it does on everyone elses machine?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a .bowerrc file that is different from everyone else? (And maybe you .gitignore . files?)

Comment: unfortunately no ... we have compared that stuff side by side

Comment: Well, there goes the easy answer :) So what OS are you on? Does it happen for another user account on your machine? What happens if you do a clean checkout/clone into a fresh directory?

Comment: Is it possible for you to get an exact copy of the project off someone else's computer?

Comment: Ok to answer ... I have gone as far as to completely remove Bower, Grunt, Node, Karma, Jasmine etc... from my computer ... (Which is OSX) ... we then deleted my local copy of the git repo ... re cloned it ... reinstalled everything that was deleted fresh and then compared the files in the repo side by side ... we cant figure it out ... all i can think is that there is a config file hiding somewhere on my system that I havnt found ... but i dont even know what to look for

Comment: Can you create a new user account on your mac and see if it has the same problem?